# Problema de layout ao trocar eclipse por IntelliJ

Tags: html, eclipse, intellij

Sou iniciante e estou no meio de um projeto.
Em função de muitos bugs de compilação, resolvi trocar o eclipse pelo IntelliJ.
Problemas de importação e conexão com banco resolvidos, posso dar continuidade ao projeto. Agora me deparei com essa situação e não sei por onde começar a pesquisar. O layout no IntelliJ ficou todo bagunçado. desconfigurou tudo. Desde o Css até propriedades setadas diretamente no elemento html. A disposição dos elementos ainda é a mesma do antigo projeto mas ele não está renderizando desta forma. Um exemplo do que acontece:

```
<img></img>
   <div></div>
```

Nesse caso a imagem teria que ficar em cima da div, porem não é o que acontece.
Ela fica por baixo ou sobrepondo em alguns casos, e isso acontece com praticamente todos os elementos. Resumindo, a disposição dos elementos é a mesma e estava alinhada no eclipse, agora no intellij nada funciona estando do mesmo jeito.

Há alguma configuração pra isso? 
O que devo pesquisar não sei por onde começo e não encontrei nada ainda sobre.

Comment: Cesar, você trocou somente de IDE? Ou trocou de navegador também? A versão do código é a mesma? A ordem em que os elementos aparecem no HTML dependem do navegador e do código. Não acredito que o IntelliJ seja responsável por isso.

Comment: Olá Rubico, o navegador e a versão são os mesmos. Na falta de um problema similar ao meu para consulta, estou definido todas as propriedades do layout do zero. Dessa forma aos poucos a coisa esta se ajeitando. Mas ainda estou sem entender o porque disso.

Comment: Quando você migrou para o IntelliJ, provavelmente a sua estrutura de pastas mudou. Talvez tenha mudado de um modo que os seus arquivos de css não estão sendo carregados. Tenta dar uma olhada no console se você está recebendo algum 404 para os seus arquivos CSS.

Comment: Foram sim, eu fiz tudo na mão a estrutura. Tive problemas para criar o gradle no projeto então quando consegui, criei todas as pastas na mão mesmo. Mas tive o cuidado de olhar tudo na aplicação, e o css está lá. O que acontece é que algumas propriedades simplesmente não estão sendo carregadas. Outras o intellij setou como erro. Como por exemplo window auto; Ele não aceitou esse valor 'auto', deu error.

Comment: Quando ele coloca como error, ele não impede de funcionar no browser, como eu disse antes. Você conferiu se está pegando algum 404 no CSS?

Comment: Conferido, sem erros no browser, mesmo setando a propriedade diretamente no elemento ele nao parece erro no browser. E com a propriedade setada no elemento a mensagem de erro no IntelliJ é de Unknown Css property window.

Comment: Não é questão de erro no browser, se estiver usando o chrome faz dessa maneira. Aperta F12 > Aba Network. Recarrega a página e vê se ele não vai apontar 404 em alguns do seus css, normalmente 404 não são apontados no console e passam dispercebidos.

Comment: Certo, estou usando o crome.Fiz aqui mas não apareceu nada. Já estou conformado e estou alterando tudo na mão. É o preço que paguei pra não me incomodar mais com o eclipse cheio de bugs.